# Count consecutive numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, count

I don't get why my method is not working.
I have a textfile which consists of a long sequence of DNA (e.g. ATTTGTTCAGCCA seen further down). My task is to count the consecutive times "AGATC" is being in the file.
My idea is to replace each AGATC in the file with "1" and then count the consecutive 1s. I count up if x[h] itself is 1 and the neighbor is 1 (second if loop), or if x[h] is NOT 1 but the neighbor is 1 (first if loop) (which should work because I don't count the last 1 with this algorithm). However, this did not work for all files e.g. file 5. The content of the file is further down.

My output is 28 for AGATC but it should be 22. Is there a mistake in my count method?
Thanks a lot!

```
from sys import argv
import csv

# make methode which replaces the argument with 1 and then counts consecutive 1s
def count(seq):
    #replace with 1 and store in x
    x = sequence.replace(seq, "1")
    # count consecutive 1s
    count = 0
    h = 0
    for i in x:
        while h < len(x) - 1:
            if x[h] != "1" and x[h+1] == "1":
                count += 1
            if x[h] == "1":
                if (x[h+1]) == "1":
                    count += 1
            h += 1

    return count

# call count method to count the AGATC, AATG and TATC sequences in 5.txt
list = [count("AGATC"), count("AATG"), count("TATC")]
print(list)
```

> GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACAAATCAAGCTGTCCGCTCGGCACGGCCTACACACGTCGTGTAACTACAACAGCTAGTTAATCTGGATATCACCATGACCGAATCATAGATTTCGCCTTAAGGAGCTTTACCATGGCTTGGGATCCAATACTAAGGGCTCGACCTAGGCGAATGAGTTTCAGGTTGGCAATCAGCAACGCTCGCCATCCGGACGACGGCTTACAGTTAGTAGCATAGTACGCGATTTTCGGGAAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCCCGTCAACTCATTCACACCGCATCCTTTCCTGCCACTGTAACTAGTCGACTGGGGAACCTCATCATCCATACTCTCCCACATTATGCCTCCCAACCTTGTTAAGCGTGGCATGCTTGGGATTGCATTGATGCTTCTTGGAGAGGACGCTTTCGTTTTGGAGATTACAGGGATCCAATTTTATCATCGGTTCGACTCCCGTAACGACTTAGCAGTAAGGGTGCTAGTTCCTGGTTAGAATCTTAATAAATCACGTCGCTTGGAGCAAGACAAAGATCGTCGTAATGCCAAGTGCACGACCACCTTCAGACTTGCAGGACCCGTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTCGATAGCTATGCGGTTCAATACAATCTTAACGCAATGCAGCGATGTGGTTTCGTACACTTAGCATAAAACCCCCCACATTAAATCGATGTACCCGCCCTCTTAGACGCCAATTTCAATGCCGAACCTCCGGCGGGTATCTCTGCACTAGGAGAAGTAGCACGTCGCTGTAGCGAACTCCTATCGTGAGATAATTTGTAGAGCTGCTCTTATAATACAATAGCTCAGATGGATTATTCCATGGACATCCCCGTGCGTTGTTTCGAGGATGGTAGGTGGAAATTTTGCCAGACCTCTAGTCTTAAACATGGTTGACGTTATAGGCGCTATCTCTTGCGTCTGGAAGTGTTAATCCGTGAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAACACGCAACTCTGGAGGAGGGCACTGCACTGCAAACTTGCGTAATATCCTTCACCCACACTTGCCTGGCCTCCTTGCTTAAAGCTCTGGCGATGCGATTTTTCGGCCCAGTAGCTGAATAGGTCATGAAATGGGCACCGAACTGGAAAGACCCATATATTCGATACTCACAACTTAATGATAGCGCGATTAAGAGCGACACCAAAAACCAAATTACGTTCACGAACCTTTGAGAGTCAAGGAGACTTAGACCGAATTGAATGATCACTGATGCGCCCGCTGATACTGAGCCTCACCATTAATCGCCGACCAATACGGCGTGTACCGGGCGCGGCCTTGCCGCATAACGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATATCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTACACAGCCCCGTCCTCATTGCTAAGTGCACTGGCAACTGGACCTAAAGATTTTTCGAGTATGGCCCTCGAATCAAGCGCCCACCCAGAAACCTACGAGCCAGTAACCCCAGTAAACAAGCATTAGTGCTATATGCTTGCTGCCCACTAGGACCCTTATGGTTCATACCAGGGTGACGTGTCTTGCGGGCCAAGGATGAACCAGAAGCAAGATCCTTAGATGGACGACTGTCTCATTGCTTAAACTCCACATACCAAAGGGCGCGGTAAACGATAGTTTTAGGTAATGTTAGTCGGATGGTTGTCTGCAGCTACCAATACAGCCTGGCACCCAGGGTCTGAACAATAACGCGTGAGAGCAGCTCTCCCGCGTGTGGTGGATTTGCCGTCTATGAAATTGAGGCTCTTGCAACTATTCGCACTCGGAATGCCCTCATATCTGGTGCCTAGCGGCCTTTGCCCCGTGCCGGTAGGACTAAACTCTACGGATCGTTGACGGATCTCGATGTGGAAGATGGTTATGAAAGATAACAACGCGTGTGCTAATTGATTTAGACAAGTATTGCGGCAGTAAAAGATAATCGGCTGCAGAGTTACGAAAGACTTCCATGCATGGATTCCATTCCTTCTAGTATAGGACCCACTCTGAATACACGTCTTGCGGGCCGATCATCTCCACCGCTGCGGAAGAAAGCAATTAAGAATCTATGCTCATTAAGAGTGCGACTATAATGCGGATCTTACAGTGCTAATGATCAGGACGTCGTCCAAGCAGGCTGCATGCCGAATTTAGCTTACGTCAGGATCAGGCGTTATAGCCTGGGAATCGGACTATGAGGACGCCACGACCTCTGGGAGAAAGCTATATACATTGAGGATCGCGCCATCTTTATGAGACTCAAATGAATCTAGATAGGTAGCATTGCGGACTTGAGTTAGCACATCGGTATTGGAAGGTGAGGGTCCTGCCGCTCGTTCTATGTTCGGTTTATAGTATACAAATAGGTCATCCCGAACGTTGAAGTTAAACTCATGACACGTTGTCGTAATGAAACGGGCCTGTTATTAGGGATACAGACAAAAGGCACAAGCTGGCTTGCACATTAAGGCGCACTAGAGATCCTCACAACCGTTGCCCGCACGGAGGTCGTGTCTAACAGACAGTGAACCAGCCGTATTGGGGTGGATGACCTGAGCTTCTTGGGGCCTGTTGTACACCGCGTGTGGTTCAACTGGTACACATACTACGAATATTCGAAATCATTGTACTGTGCTCTTCGGTGCTACTGACTGTGAGCGAATGCATCCCAATCCCAAACAATGCTTGTGGTAGGAGAATTGAAACTCTCGAAGCCTGGCCCAATGTCATCTACTTTTAACATGTCGGGCCAGGAGTTACGGGCATTGCTTACTTACTTTGCCCCCTTACACCACAGCAGCGCGATTCTTGTTGTAGTAGATTTTATACGACTCGCGAATTAAATGGAACTTGTCTGTCCCATATCGATCGTGTCCATCGTAAGATGAGATTGTAGGAGCATTCGGAAGTCTATGCGGCCCAGGGACTACTACGTTAAATCTGGTCAGACGTGGTTTACAAGGCGTCCCGATCTTCTCAGAACATATGGGAAAGCACTACCGTTCCTTCACGCATACAGTTGTTCGTGCCGAACGAGTAAGCTTGCGACCAGCCCACCCGCTAGGGCTATGCAGCGGGTCATGGCTGGCGCCATACTGTGCGGACAACCCACGCTCTGGCAGAAAGCGTCTTGTGTTTTGTAGTAGCTCCAACGGTTAGACCTTCGATATCTATTCAGAGCGCGAGCGACCACTATTAGACGGCATGTAAACAATGTGTATTTGTTCGGCCCAACCGGTATATGGGTAAGACCGCGAAGGGCCTGCGCGAATACCAGCGTCCAAAAATTCCTCACCCGAGATATGCGGTTAGTACCCCTTGGGTAACGGTCCGCTACGGGTAGCGACGCGAGCCGGCCGCATCGGTTGGAGCCGAGTTGTCGGGCAGGCGAGTAACGTGTGCAATTTGATGGGCCCAAGCCTCCGGCACTATCCACCTCATACATCGACAAAAGCACCAAATATGGGGAAAAGCTGAGCGTCGATATGTACATCTACCCAGGAACCGGCCCGAACATTAGGCGGACGTGAATTTCCGACCTAGGTTCGGCTACATTTCTACGATCCAAGCACACGTGAAGGAGGAGGGGTGTTCCGACCGTAAATGAACGAGGTGCGCAGTGACCCGATGGCGTTTAGCGGATAGCCTTCCTATGCCGGCCTATGCTGTATGGTAGTTGGTTGGTGCCTCCAGAGCCACTGCACCCAATCATAGGGTCTACAGCAGCGTACTTATAAAATTGTACGGGTGACCCATATCCATTACGGGTTGCGACCAGTATAGGAGAGTATAACTGCGTGAACTAATGCGTTATGACGCTTCAGAGTTTGCTCGGGCCCGAGTTCTAGGGCTATAATGTGTTAGGGCGCAAGTATGCCAAGCTAAGATGTGGCGTGCACACTAGGAGTTGTGTTCCTCTGCAAGCAGACACGAGCACTCTGGCAGTAGTTTGACCACACCCGGGTATCACTGCTACTCCATTTCGAACAAGCTATTGGAGCGGACAAAATATGCTACTCAAGAGCATTAGTTATAGGTCTACGAGACAGAAGCAGTTACTGAGTCTGAATATTCGATATAAGTAGGCATGGAGGCGGAGCAAAACAACGTCTGCGATCAATCGTGTTGATGACGTATGGCGACTGGAAGGTAAGGACTATGGCCGGACGGAATGATTCATGTTCTGTTCAAAGCTATATTTCGAAGGGGTATATTAGCGGTCCTACACTTGGTTAGCACCCTCCCCCCTCTGGATCCTGCACTAATTCGAGCTGGCCTCCATCGGTATCAGTCCGGAAGCTCCACTCTCTATCGTAGTCCTAATCAACAGGGTGCCAGTTTGCTCACGTGGAAGTTTGAGGCCCTTTGTGCTCCATAGCCAATCACTAACCATGCACGCGCGACCCACTCTACGTCCAGATCGGCTATAATAGTTGCGCCCGGGACTGGCAGAGTAGACATGTAAGCTAGATAGAGCCCCGACATCGGCCAAGAGATCCTACGCTGCTTCCAGATAATGAGAGACATTCTAGCATTAGACATGCAAGTCGGCAGGGACTCCCCTTATCTAGTAATTTCGATGAATTGGTTTTTCGGCTAGCATCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGACCATGCCGACCTCATCATAGAAGGAATGCTCTAAACTTAGAGTGCTACTAGGAAAACTATTAATCAATGATCGTCCTGCTTACATAGCTGGACGGCGAAAGTTCTTATACTGCGGAGGTTGCTGACGTAGAGTGCGCTGGGTACAGCGGATAAGTTGATCAGGGTGGGGATAGGGTGGCTCACCGTTTATACTCATATAGATTCCTGGCGTCGACGCTGTGACAGGGTCGAGATCGAGGGGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGCGGAGCGGAGGGAAAATTATCACCAGAGGGTAGGGGCTCGCGACATTCTATTCAATGCATTTCAAGCTACTTACGTATTTCGGCACAGTGACTACTGCCTGCGCGGCAGCCGTAAGGTTTCCCGTCAATAGGTGGCACGTATCATTGATGAAAGTGTCAGCTAATCATTCAGGCCTTA

Comment: How is `sequence` initialized? Also FYI don't use `count` for both a function name and a local variable.

Comment: Also don't use `list` as a variable name :) Shadows built-in name 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you another solution with a smaller complexity:

```
yourString = "GCTAAATTTGTTCAGCCAGATGTAGGCTTACA....".replace("AGATC", "1")
count = 0
finalCount = 0
for character in yourString:
    if character == "1":
        count += 1
        if finalCount <= count:
            finalCount = count
    else:
        count = 0
print(finalCount)
```

This will itterate everytime it encounters `1`'s. Also it will add to `finalCount` the highest found value for the count. At the end, you'll have the highest sequence you're searching for

Comment: Ah, now I see my mistake, I was so focused on counting neighbors but I didn't store the highest value. I just counted up when I got a 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use count as a variable name if count is the function name
2. It looks like you are using the variable sequence from outside scope. It's better to also pass it as an argument.
3. By consecutive I assume it means the **longest** consecutive count? In that case, you need to add a variable to store the longest consecutive count, and set your counter to 0 whenever the chain ends. Then, start counting again when it continues.

Comment: Ooooh, I got it, I got 28 because in total there are 28 AGATC in the string. But only 22 consecutives. Indeed, I forgot to store the highest value!! Thanks a lot! That really helped! Can't believe that took me so long haha. And regarding the naming of the variables you are right, I should consider this more in the future.